# mouseover super slow on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, webkit

Made this animation and it works super fast on Webkit browsers and mobile, but not on firefox. Wondering if there might be something specific about firefox or jquery which is making it slow to change slides.

```
/* hover function */

  function changeSlide(slideNo){
    $('.slide-active').removeClass('slide-active');
    $('.motion-container img:eq('+slideNo+')').addClass('slide-active');
  }

  $('.hover').mouseover(function(){
    $slideNo = $(this).attr('no-data');
    changeSlide($slideNo);
  });
```

http://nicegrp.co.uk/dev/skateboard/deviceMotion.html

Comment: maybe firefox doesnt like your php'ish variables? :P put a console.log at the beginning of your hover function and check if it's really the mouseover function that's slow. btw: your link is hardly buggy for me in chrome as well..

Comment: Also make sure you properly declare local variables (well, global ones too) with `var`.  Add `"use strict";` as the very first line of "motion.js" and the browser will yell at you appropriately when you've forgotten to declare variables.

Comment: `mouseover` fires continuously, how about trying `mouseenter` instead

Comment: Thanks, will try those comments, thanks